Oracle EntityFramework can no longer handle boolean using EF
I have just updated from NET7 to NET8. Also updated all MS packages to 8.0.7.
Have listed some of the packages including EF for Oracle.
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFrameworkCore.Exceptions.Oracle" Version="8.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.23.50" />

Before I upgraded, I could run this query, without any problems
   [HttpGet("CanDelete/{id:long}")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> CanDelete(long id)
   {
        var inUse = await _dbContext.CompositeFunds.AnyAsync(x => x.FundId == id);    
        return Ok(!inUse);
   }

Now it creates this sql and fail on True/False
[10:49:05 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (67ms) [Parameters=[:id_0='1033'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "PERFORMANCE"."COMPOSITE_FUND" "c"
        WHERE "c"."FUND" = :id_0) THEN True
    ELSE False
END FROM DUAL
[10:49:05 ERR] 2024-08-08 10:49:05.139123 ThreadID:35  (ERROR)   OracleExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00904: "FALSE": ugyldig identifikator
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00904/

I also have the same problem when using boolean in my entities.
This used to work:
builder.Property(e => e.Active).HasColumnName("ACTIVE").IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0);

Now I have to add this:
builder.Property(e => e.Active).HasColumnName("ACTIVE").IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(0).HasColumnType("NUMBER");

Looks like everything that results in a boolean fails.
I looked for breaking changes, but could not find anything related to booleans.

Just downgraded to Oracle EF version 8.21.150 and now the sql works.
8.21.150 is the latest version that works.
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "PERFORMANCE"."COMPOSITE_FUND" "c"
        WHERE "c"."FUND" = :item_FundId_0) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END FROM DUAL


As suggested I just use
override ConfigureConventions and add configurationBuilder.Properties().HasColumnType("NUMBER").
That will fix it

Looks like convention for boolean fields was changed. You can overide this during configuring conventions override ConfigureConventions and add configurationBuilder.Properties<bool>().HasColumnType("NUMBER").

Thanks. If this is true, then it will break a lot of code. I hope they fix it.
If not, I will use your suggestion

Which Oracle version are you using? The Breaking Changes page says that by default Oracle's provider expects a matching Oracle database and client version, eg 23 or 21. You may be able to use UseOracleSQLCompatibility with the latest provider to specify a lower version

Hah. Oracle 23 added a true Boolean type so True is now valid

I have found this difference in the MigrationBuilder code when I started rebuilding a table column by column to find out which was causing the error.
When I added the "LOGGING_ENABLED" column and created the migration using the latest Oracle EF Core it was
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "LOGGING_ENABLED",
        table: "APP_SETTINGS",
        type: "BOOLEAN",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: false);
}

but when I rolled back to 150 as you suggested the type field becomes NUMBER(1)
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "LOGGING_ENABLED",
        table: "APP_SETTINGS",
        type: "NUMBER(1)",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: false);
}

So, it appears MigrationBuilder is trying to assign "BOOLEAN" where Oracle doesn't recognize it.

The question is about querying, not migrations. Oracle didn't have a Boolean type until v23 and like most databases used another numeric type for boolean flags. This isn't a recent change. Oracle 23 does recognize Boolean

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

I suspect you're using an older Oracle version. Oracle 23 added a Boolean type so TRUE is now a valid value.
The Breaking Changes page of Oracle's EF Provider explains that by default the provider assumes that database, Oracle Client and EF Provider versions match, so Oracle EF Core 8.23 expects to find Oracle 23.
Emphasis mine .......

In EF Core 6 and higher versions with Oracle EF Core version 23, UseOracleSQLCompatibility extension method now takes an enumeration type as an argument rather than a string value. This extension method's default value will be the same as the Oracle EF Core version. For example, if you are using Oracle EF Core 23, then its value will be OracleSQLCompatibility.DatabaseVersion23.


This default assumes the app is using the same database version as the Oracle EF Core version, that is, Oracle Database 23ai with Oracle 23ai client. If they are not the same version, then the developer should modify the enumeration value to match the database version they are connecting to. This ensures fewer compatibility errors and allows Oracle EF Core to use the latest Oracle Database features.

I think you should keep using the 8.21 versions (now at 8.21.160) instead of using UseOracleSQLCompatibility, unless there's a feature you can't live without. 8.21.160 was released at the same time as 8.23.60, so the 8.21 versions are still actively supported.
